# Override components/com_users/models/forms/login.xml - Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla1.6, joomla-template, joomla2.5

I've been trying to override the file `login.xml` but no matter what I try, the edited version in my template folder doesn't show up.
How can I override this file?

**Update**

I have tried `template/<templatename>/html/com_users/models/login.xml` and other variations like `template/<templatename>/html/com_users/models/forms/login.xml` or `template/<templatename>/html/com_users/forms/login.xml` etc without any success.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried template/templatename/html/com_users/models/login.xml and other variations like template/templatename/html/com_users/models/forms/login.xml or template/templatename/html/com_users/forms/login.xml etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=583380#p2375649

I just tested it in Joomla 2.5.3 and it works.

**Update**

here is the solution copied from above URL

We can override output by using the normal template override feature. For me, I'm trying to override the login page. So, I'm taking a copy of `/components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default.php` and putting it into `/templates/beez_20/html/com_users/login`.

Now take a copy of `/components/com_users/models/forms/login.xml` and place in `/templates/beez_20/html/com_users/login` as well.

Then edit `/templates/beez_20/html/com_users/login/default.php` and add at the top of the form (I added mine just after the form tag) the following lines of code:

```
// to reset the form xml loaded by the view
$this->form->reset( true );

// to load in our own version of login.xml
$this->form->loadFile( dirname(__FILE__) . DS . "login.xml");
```

Similarly you can safely edit `/templates/beez_20/html/com_users/registration/registration.xml` to modify the registration form.

Comment: Is there any way to override the module xml file?

Answer (score 6):

The answer posted in the forum that @Shaz definitely works, but for Joomla 3.X you have to tweak a little, so it would be

First of all you copy

```
/components/com_users/models/forms/login.xml
```

To

```
/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/forms/login.xml
```

And place this piece of code right at the top

```
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$this->form->reset( true ); // to reset the form xml loaded by the view
$this->form->loadFile( dirname(__FILE__) . DS . "forms" . DS . "login.xml"); // to load in our own version of login.xml
```

This did the tick for me a kudos for the user @dylanjh that posted the original answer on the Joomla forum

Comment: You can simply replace the DS with regular '/': $this->form->loadFile( dirname(__FILE__) . "/forms/login.xml");

Answer (score 2):

I was able to leverage Griiettner's solution for Joomla 3. I wanted to not allow users to edit their email address in the profile edit screen on the frontend. I only modified it slightly, copy this file:

`components/com_users/models/forms/profile.xml`

to:

`/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/profile/forms/profile.xml`

Also copy this file:

`components/com_users/views/profile/tmpl/edit.php`

to:

`/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_users/profile/edit.php`

And put this code at the top of the edit.php file right after the:

`defined('_JEXEC') or die;`

I left out the `$this->form->reset( true ); // to reset the form xml loaded by the view`
and only used this:

`// JOOMLA 3 
if(!defined('DS')) define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$this->form->loadFile( dirname(__FILE__) . DS . "forms" . DS . "profile.xml");`

This allowed me to keep the user profile information populated in the edit form. I then edited the profile.xml file and added:

`readonly="true"`

to the email1 and email2 fields. This prevents the user from editing.