# How to add extra fields on Joomla user profile edit form?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I am using Joomla 2.5 inbuilt registration form .After successful user log-in their is a option for user to view and edit their profile.I need to change label of that edit profile form . how to change Please Help me I am new to Joomla .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an easy way to **translate** everything in joomla.
You have to go to:

```
Extensions -> Language Manager -> Overrides -> New
```

There is a **search** option available. You could select the string you want to translate and add an **override**.

Hope this helps

Comment: No..! actually their is some fields are optional i need to make those compulsory(or just need to remove that "optional") please help

Comment: Please check `/components/com_users/models/forms/profile.xml` and change `required` status.

Comment: This is a core joomla change and will be lost after update. In order to make an override of this file you have to folow these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9855024.