# Override components/com_users/models/forms/login.xml add class - Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm working on the default login page in Joomla 3.
I overrided

```
/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/default_login.php
```

and it's working fine but in that file to generate the form field it uses JForm, which create the html tags using :

```
/components/com_users/models/forms/login.xml
```

Now what I would like to do is override that file to add an additional class to the input field. I tried several combinations:

```
/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_users/login.xml
/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/login.xml  
/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_users/models/forms/login.xml
/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_users/models/login.xml
```

No one of them is working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override components/com\_users/models/forms/login.xml - Joomla 2.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854626/override-components-com-users-models-forms-login-xml-joomla-2-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854626/override-components-com-users-models-forms-login-xml-joomla-2-5)

You can copy login.xml and default.php in

```
/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/forms/login.xml 
/templates/MYTEMPLATE/html/com_users/login/default.php
```

After you have to edit default.php and add the following lines

```
$this->form->reset( true );   
$this->form->loadFile( dirname(__FILE__) . DS . "forms" . DS . "login.xml");
```

Once you do that you can edit login.xml

In my case I just added form-control to the attribute class

```
<field name="username" type="text"
        class="validate-username form-control"
        filter="username"
        label="COM_USERS_LOGIN_USERNAME_LABEL"
        size="25"
        required="true"
        validate="username"
    />
```